# How to configure OMS agent to report heartbeat, Syslogs, Perf to same workspace?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have a scenario where few **Linux** servers are sending Heartbeat and syslog to two different LA (Log Analytics) workspaces. I need help in configuration to send both to the same workspace.

Current: Heartbeat in workspace1 and Syslog in workspace2

Desired: Both Heartbeat and Syslog to be reported in workspace1

- The other doubt in regards with this is "dual-homing". Is this a dual homing scenario? Coz I've read the LA documentation says that dual-homing is not supported for Linux OMS agent. And in contradiction, I've seen some SCOM articles saying dual homing is feasible for Linux machines by configuring OMS over SCOM.

[Multi-homing agent blog post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38fcbd0b-7908-4f18-bfa0-7445efeff88a/unixlinux-servers-multihoming-monitoring-issue-in-scom-2016-and-oms?forum=operationsmanagergeneral)

[Microsoft site ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msoms/oms-log-analytics-agent-multi-homing-support)

[No Dual Homing Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/log-analytics-agent#overview)

The first two links might be outdated. So might be the case I'm dealing with, as the agent installation on these machines might be done a long time back.

The last link we can find the statement no multi-homing in the overview ( search: "multi-homing")

Comment: Could you tell me how you send Heartbeat to  LA ?

Comment: @JimXu Sending it using the omsagent, onboarded using the onboard_agent.sh and the workspace details. But, not sure if these are reconfigured/ modified.

Comment: According to my research, when we install the agent, we call choose LA workspace(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-linux) . SoI think they can be sent to the same LA

Comment: @Jim Xu, exactly, you specify the workspace during onboarding. But in my scenario as I mentioned they are reporting to different workspaces. That's why I wanted to know if some configuration modification can change that. Or if dualhomed, and thus reporting each to separate workspaces.

Comment: Can this be something to do with an earlier SCOM configurations? If so, how do I ensure that the previous configurations are cleared?